# Unresolved reference when declaring variable type from inner class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, types, inner-classes

I have the following class: `TestOne`, `TestTwo`, `TestThree`, and `TestFour`. The class `TestTwo`, `TestThree`, and `TestFour` are inner class of `TestOne`. In `TestThree`, i used `isinstance(test_three_input, TestOne.TestTwo)` without error, however in `TestFour`, i tried to declare that the variable type should be `TestTwo`, but it gave me unresolved reference error.

```
class TestOne:
    class TestTwo:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

    class TestThree:
        def __init__(self, test_three_input):
            if isinstance(test_three_input, TestOne.TestTwo):
                print("yes")
            else:
                print("no")

    class TestFour:
        def __init__(self, test_four_input: TestOne.TestTwo):  # unresolved reference error
            pass
```

The error is `Unresolved reference 'TestOne'`. What is the reason behind this error and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/):

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

to delay evaluation of annotations. This works for python 3.7+. It was scheduled to become the default behavior in python 3.10, but is delayed to later releases beyond 3.11.

Comment: thank you this worked, i no longer get the error, i will look forward in the documentation on why this is a thing